# Uploaded test cases on TFS are not visible in Test Manager

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I have uploaded some test cases form excel sheet in TFS under a specified project using 'Test case import utility' yet i am not able to see uploaded test cases in MTM for execution. Is there anything i might have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario one must query the test cases in MTM and there it will list all the test cases, test cases can then be directly added to MTM corresponding to a particular suit.

Comment: You should mark an answer as one which solve your problem so the others who are facing the same problem can benefit from it.